# Virtual StringTree: Text returned by the OnGetHint event handler is not shown in the hint window

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I wrote a handler for the OnGetHint event of the Virtual StringTree control, and I'm sure that the hint text is returned, but the hint window is blank, see the screenshot below, what might caused this problem? thank you in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

The settings of the control:

```
AnimationDuration := 0;
ClipboardFormats.Clear;
ClipboardFormats.Add('HTML Format');
ClipboardFormats.Add('Plain text');
ClipboardFormats.Add('Rich Text Format');
ClipboardFormats.Add('Rich Text Format Without Objects');
ClipboardFormats.Add('Unicode text');
ClipboardFormats.Add('Virtual Tree Data');
DefaultPasteMode := amInsertBefore;
DragOperations := [doCopy, doMove, doLink];
EditDelay := 200;
HintMode := hmHint;
Images := dmImages.lstProjectTree;
IncrementalSearch := isAll;
Indent := 16;
Margin := 0;
ParentFont := False;
PopupMenu := pmTree;
SelectionCurveRadius := 5;
OnCollapsed := treePrjCollapsed;
OnColumnClick := treePrjColumnClick;
OnDblClick := treePrjDblClick;
OnDragAllowed := treePrjDragAllowed;
OnDragOver := treePrjDragOver;
OnDragDrop := treePrjDragDrop;
OnExpanded := treePrjExpanded;
OnFocusChanged := treePrjFocusChanged;
OnGetCursor := treePrjGetCursor;
OnGetText := treePrjGetText;
OnPaintText := treePrjPaintText;
OnGetImageIndexEx := treePrjGetImageIndexEx;
OnGetHint := treePrjGetHint;
OnKeyDown := treePrjKeyDown;
OnMouseDown := treePrjMouseDown;
OnNewText := treePrjNewText;
OnNodeMoving := treePrjNodeMoving;
with Columns.Add do begin
  Position := 0;
  Width := 153;
end;
with Columns.Add do begin
  Layout := blGlyphRight;
  MinWidth := 20;
  Position := 1;
  Width := 20;
end;
with Columns.Add do begin
  Layout := blGlyphRight;
  MinWidth := 20;
  Position := 2;
  Width := 20;
end;
with Columns.Add do begin
  Layout := blGlyphRight;
  MinWidth := 16;
  Position := 3;
  Width := 20;
end;
```

Comment: If you're so sure you're setting the hint text correctly, prove it. Show the code. Include at least some of the OnGetText handler, too.

Comment: Sorry for the link, it is: <BR>
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/367923/Screenshots/Virtual%20TreeView%20OnGetHint%20Problem.JPG
<BR>
<BR>
@Rob,

for the testing purpose I'm using this code:<br>
HintText := 'my testing hint text'; <BR>
Moreover, if no hint text the hint window will not be shown.

Comment: Hi,

I found the culprit of the problem! It's AnimationDuration := 0;

Comment: Add that as an answer, Edwin. You'll be able to mark it as the accepted answer. Also, easy on the <br> tags; they don't work in comments, and in answers, you make a new paragraph with a blank line.

Comment: Rob, I guess he did prove it :-)

Comment: I suppose so, François. The screen shot was very helpful in explaining the problem. Before the image was available, I expected it would be fully painted, but without any text, and maybe it was being painted as a very small rectangle (as though it was sized for an empty string). But in fact the entire surface of the hint window was missing; it had nothing to do with the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the culprit of the problem myself! It's AnimationDuration := 0

As Rob suggested, I added this finding as the answer so that I can accept it.