# Virtual StringTree's hint windows are left out on the screen

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

See this screenshot, in the middle it's the small hint windows that are generated by a TVirtualStringTree control and were left out on the screen, these hint windows will remain there until the application exits. the problem happens when the treeview's hint is shown and the mouse leaves quickly to the window next to it.

Any idea about how to avoid this or how to clear those un-erased hint windows if it's difficult to avid this?

[image]

Few days ago I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091141/virtual-stringtree-text-returned-by-the-ongethint-event-handler-is-not-shown-in), while the hint windows in the screenshots look the same, the are not the same problem. That problem, the hint text never shows and only that kind of uncompleted hint windows are shown; This problem, the hint text shows but the hint windows are not completely erased in a case (as I described above). Hope it's clear.

Comment: Is your program busy in some kind of loop? This is no normal behaviour for VirtualTree hints or even regular hints. Have you tried running the program on another machine, does it behave the same?

Comment: Hi Remko, It's not busy in some kind of loop. And I forgot to mention that it's a Word addin... Maybe it's hard to find the cause of the problem, but are we able to to clear those hint window leftovers?

Answer (score 1):

Does it help to just repaint the window?

Comment: No, even refreshing the whole computer desktop does not help, those seems to be standalone windows, but not unpainted window areas...

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Word addin that may be a reason.

Maybe you should create your own hint window class (inherit from TVirtualTreeHintWindow) which instance you can manage by yourself and then override the GetHintWindowClass method to use this class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, straveu! What special actions my own hint window should do? A small sample is appreciated!